# Visual Studio Code не подсвечивает JavaScript код

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Здравствуйьте, в один прикрасный момент в VS Code ухудшиласб цветная подсветка кода
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может раньше сталкивались, знаете в чем может быть дело и как исправить

Comment: какой файл открыт?

Comment: какое расширение у файла? .js? .ts?

Comment: @Diamon А какая разница? Если файл перенести на .ts вместо .js подсветка всё равно будет работать (по идее) и сам код будет выполниться также.

Comment: @ΝNL993, подсветка настраивается на тип файлов, например, поэтому если был js, а стал ts - то все может сломаться.

Comment: Та же проблема с `vue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего у вас установлено расширение [JavaScript and TypeScript Nightly](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.vscode-typescript-next), отключите его, пока в нем не исправят проблему.

Comment: Всё обновили. Проблема ушла.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло !